# Google Chart Table Remove the selection

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

I am currently working with the Google chart tables. I have a problem with the selections. I want to turn the selections off, but it seems to be impossible. I even tried (an real ugly way) like an event listener on the select part that uses the method [clearChart()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#Methods) to remove this.

Here is the test sourche code. Note that i cant use this in jsfiddle

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load("jquery", "1");

google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table']});

     function drawVisualization()
     {
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['', 'Name', 'E-mail', 'Activated', 'Last login'],
          ['<input type="checkbox">', 'name1', 'name1@company.xxx', true, '20-07-2012'],
          ['<input type="checkbox">', 'name2', 'name2@company.xxx', true, '21-07-2012']

               ]);

               var options = {};
               options['showRowNumber'] = false;
               options['page'] = 'enable';
               options['allowHtml'] = true;
               options['pageSize'] = 18;
               options['pagingButtonsConfiguration'] = 'auto';

               var visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
               visualization.draw(data, options);
          }

          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

</script>
<div id="table"></div>
```

The problem is that if I use these checkboxes the (blue) selection is anoying and confusing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Another option is to reset the selection when the "select" event is fired:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(visualization, 'select', selectHandler);

function selectHandler() {  
    visualization.setSelection([])
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Rxnty/

This immediately removes the selection without requiring a redraw.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the "best" way to do it. Shame on Google it can't be disabled instead of override!

Comment: This fixes the issue when the user wants to click multiple times in the chart

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve what the effect you desire is to tell the API what class should be applied when the row is selected, allowing you to keep specify the `background-color` of the row.

**JS:**

```
options['cssClassNames'] = {}
options['cssClassNames']['selectedTableRow'] = 'selected';
```

**CSS:**

```
.selected { background-color: white; }
```

You can see it working on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/rjvAL/3/).

Comment: While it may not be an ideal solution (rather than ugly), it just gives you a way of overriding Google's default styles.

Comment: Isnt there a way to avoid instead of override?

Comment: According to the docs https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#Configuration_Options that's the only way I could see to do it... `getSelection()` doesn't return the right data to create this functionality. How close were you with `clearChart()`?